# Looping How can I make the barking 5 times and the dog running 10

Tags: c#

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   namespace Assignment07
   {

    class Dog
    {
        public void bark(string dogsName)
        {
            int barking =5;
            while(barking>5)


            Console.WriteLine(dogsName + " is barking");
        }

        public void run(string dogsName)
        {
            int running =10;
            while (running > 10)

            Console.WriteLine(dogsName + " is running");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dog fido = new Dog();
            fido.bark("Fido");
            fido.run("Fido");
            Console.Write("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true);
        }


    }
}
```

The code doesn't work. I cant get it loop. It will not work. I cant figure out to get them to go 10 or 5 times. Is there any more able to help me out ? I will be happy to figure this out because I been on it for an hour or more

Comment: Your while loops are never  running. You set `barking` to 5, then say `if barking is greater than 5`, which will never be true.

Comment: Also, passing the dog's name to the functions is a bit against best practice: one can assume that a dog's name is constant (otherwise the poor animal will get highly confused :)) so it would be more appropriate to set it once, eg by passing the name as an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the corrected code for barking, you should be able to fix run with that as well

```
    public void bark(string dogsName)
    {
        int barking = 0;
        while(barking < 5){
            barking = barking + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(dogsName + " is barking");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int barking =5;
while(barking>5)
```

Since barking will never become higher than five, the while loop will never run.

```
 int running =10;
 while (running > 10)
```

Same problem here.

Try this:

```
    public void bark(string dogsName)
    {
        int barking = 0;
        while(barking < 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dogsName + " is barking");
            barking++;
        }
    }
```

I'm gonna let you fix the running method by yourself.

**Update, to show how to have the loop outside of the method**

Change the bark method so it does not loop:

```
public void bark(string dogsName)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dogsName + " is barking");
}
```

Instead, call the bark() method in a loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dog fido = new Dog();
    int barking = 0;
    while (barking < 5)
    {
         fido.bark("Fido");
         barking++;
    }

    Console.Write("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: the loop shouldn't be in the methods themselves

Comment: Then just move the loop out of the method and call the bark method inside the loop.

Comment: will this still have the loop ?? I'm sorry I don't understand. Thank u for ur help !

Comment: If you want it to bark multiple times, then yes, of course you'll still use a loop.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this class.

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BarksOut { get; set; }
    public int RunOuts { get; set; }

    public Dog(string name, string id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }

    public void Bark(int barksNumber)
    {
        for(var i =0; i < barksNumber; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} >> {1} is barking", Id, Name);

        BarksOut += barksNumber;
    }

    public void Run(int runs)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < runs; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} >> {1} is running", Id, Name);

        RunOuts += runs;
    }

    public void Lie(long lies)
    {
        if (lies == 0)
            return;

        for (var i = 0; i < lies; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} >> {1} if lying", Id, Name);
    }
}
```

And as example of use:

```
        var dog = new Dog("Fido", "K9");

        dog.Bark(5);

        dog.Run(10);

        dog.Lie(0)
```

Output is:

```
    K9 : Fido is barking
    K9 : Fido is barking
    K9 : Fido is barking
    K9 : Fido is barking
    K9 : Fido is barking
    K9 : Fido is running
    K9 : Fido is running
    K9 : Fido is running
    K9 : Fido is running
    K9 : Fido is running
    K9 : Fido is running
    K9 : Fido is running
    K9 : Fido is running
    K9 : Fido is running
    K9 : Fido is running
```

Have fun!

Comment: May I ask: why? What tasks makes you want that?